# ASP.NET AJAX and UserControls: handling client side scripting

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a UserControl that I want to include in a page multiple times programatically based on some business rules. Currently the control has a JavaScript function that must be called on the ASP.NET AJAX `pageLoad` event.

I'm using a pattern where the Master page has a `pageLoad` function that calls a `contentPageLoad` function on any ContentTemplate, if the function exists. The ContentTemplate that holds the UserControl in question would then be responsible for calling the appropriate function on the UserControl during this event.

Right now, the JavaScript is inline in the `.ascx` for the UserControl, but I have a feeling that I'll need to use the `Page.ClientScript` property to inject it via code behind. My question is: how do I make sure that my function names don't get clobbered, and make sure that the appropriate method gets called for **each** UserControl?

FYI: the code that needs to get executed for each UserControl is a block of jQuery that creates a Multi-Select control from a standard HTML `<select>`.

**EDIT:** `RegisterStartupScript` was suggested, but this runs before the DOM is finished loading. Wrapping the function in a jQuery Document.ready() doesn't seem to help. The user control is running inside of an `UpdatePanel`, so I don't really have a choice about how to call this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up taking a hybrid approach to what @DDaviesBrackett suggested. I am registering a function with `Page.ClientScript`, not as a startup script, but as a ClientScriptBlock. The function uses classes instead of IDs (and thus, `ClientID`s) to attach to each control. The basic structure is:

```
if(!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(),"scriptkey"))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        Page.GetType(),"scriptkey",script,true);
}
```

with the following script:

```
function bindMultiSelects() {
    $('.multiselectclass').multiSelect({
        oneOrMoreSelected: '*', 
        noneSelected: 'Select Item(s)'
    });
}
```

(using the awesome [jQuery MultiSelect plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/62))

Again, this works because my Master page creates a `page_load` method that then calls a method on the content, which then calls `bindMultiSelects`. Just for my own reference, the `page_load` and `contentPageLoad` functions both follow this "plugin" pattern I found [here](http://encosia.com/2007/11/20/using-pageload-in-both-master-and-content-pages/):

```
if(typeof functionname=='function') {
    functionname()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the `ClientID` of the user control in the JS function definition:

```
function onLoadInitialize_<%=ClientID%>(){/*do things*/}
```

and then use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to cause it to happen during client-onLoad.  Be aware that [`page_load` happens on every asynchronous postback](http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/); if you want things only to happen once per actual page load (excluding async postbacks), use the init event instead.

Comment: That was my first instinct, but `ClientId` doesn't exist in the context of the UserControl. Would I need to inherit from a certain class or interface?

Comment: Whoops, had a typo (ClientID should have a capital 'D') but I'm still not sure how to handle calling each of these functions on the AJAX page load (to my knowledge, client onLoad will only happen on the first page load.)

Comment: updated answer - page_load will actually happen on every async postback, which I think is what you want.

Comment: It sounds like your approach is on the right track, but RegisterStartupScript doesn't hook into page_load auto-magically, that I can see anyway. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: it doesn't hook automagically, no. You'll want to look into Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager's event hooks (MSDN has all the documentation).